# Page reloads before hitting the server side processing page. Any ideas why?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, alert, ajaxform

The following code is using JSON object with several ajax calls to a webmethod that posts data to the database.

The issue we are having is when I click the submit button, the page reloads before data is processed thereby causing an error that says @paremeter is required but not supplied. This happens to all the form fields that are being passed to asp.net codebehind for processing.

I am having difficulty figuring out why this is happening.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
                        function getAllEmpData() {
                            var data = [];
                            $('tr.data-contact-person0').each(function () {
                                var ename = $(this).find('.employeename01').val();
                                var etitle = $(this).find('.employeetitle01').val();
                                var email = $(this).find('.employeeemail01').val();
                                var alldata = {
                                    'emplName': ename,
                                    'emplTitle': etitle,
                                    'empMail': email
                                }
                                data.push(alldata);
                            });
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        }

                        function getAllSourcepData() {
                            var data = [];
                            $('tr.data-contact-person1').each(function () {
                                var sname = $(this).find('.sourcename01').val();
                                var saddress = $(this).find('.sourceaddress01').val();
                                var sincome = $(this).find('.sourceincome01').val();
                                var alldata = {
                                    'mySource': sname,
                                    'mySAddress': saddress,
                                    'mySIncome': sincome
                                }
                                data.push(alldata);
                            });
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        }

                        function getAllSpouseData() {
                            var data = [];
                            $('tr.data-contact-person2').each(function () {
                                var spname = $(this).find('.spousename01').val();
                                var spaddress = $(this).find('.spouseaddress01').val();
                                var spincome = $(this).find('.spouseincome01').val();
                                var alldata = {
                                    'mySpouse': spname,
                                    'mySPAddress': spaddress,
                                    'mySPIncome': spincome
                                }
                                data.push(alldata);
                            });
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        }
                        function getAllDividentData() {
                            var data = [];
                            $('tr.data-contact-person3').each(function () {
                                var divname = $(this).find('.dividentname01').val();
                                var divaddress = $(this).find('.dividentaddress01').val();
                                var divincome = $(this).find('.dividentincome01').val();
                                var alldata = {
                                    'myDivName': divname,
                                    'myDivAddress': divaddress,
                                    'myDivIncome': divincome
                                }
                                data.push(alldata);
                            });
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        }
                        function getAllReimbursedData() {
                            var data = [];
                            $('tr.data-contact-person4').each(function () {
                                var reimname = $(this).find('.reimbursmentname01').val();
                                var reimaddress = $(this).find('.reimbursmentaddress01').val();
                                var reimincome = $(this).find('.reimbursmentincome01').val();
                                var alldata = {
                                    'myReimbursName': reimname,
                                    'myReimbursAddress': reimaddress,
                                    'myReimbursIncome': reimincome
                                }
                                data.push(alldata);
                            });
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        }
                        function getAllHonorariaData() {
                            var data = [];
                            $('tr.data-contact-person5').each(function () {
                                var honorname = $(this).find('.inputHonoraria01').val();
                                var alldata = {
                                    'myHonorname': honorname
                                }
                                data.push(alldata);
                            });
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        }
                        function getAllGiftData() {
                            var data = [];
                            $('tr.data-contact-person6').each(function () {
                                var gifname = $(this).find('.giftname01').val();
                                var gifaddress = $(this).find('.giftaddress01').val();
                                var gifincome = $(this).find('.giftincome01').val();
                                var alldata = {
                                    'myGiftname': gifname,
                                    'myGiftaddress': gifaddress,
                                    'myGiftincome': gifincome
                                }
                                data.push(alldata);
                            });
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        }
                        function getAllOrgData() {
                            var data = [];
                            $('tr.data-contact-person7').each(function () {
                                var orgsname = $(this).find('.orgname01').val();
                                var orgsaddress = $(this).find('.orgaddress01').val();
                                var orgsincome = $(this).find('.orgincome01').val();
                                var alldata = {
                                    'myOrgname': orgsname,
                                    'myOrgaddress': orgsaddress,
                                    'myOrgincome': orgsincome
                                }
                                data.push(alldata);
                            });
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        }
                        function getAllCreditorData() {
                            var data = [];
                            $('tr.data-contact-person8').each(function () {
                                var creditname = $(this).find('.creditorname01').val();
                                var creditaddress = $(this).find('.creditoraddress01').val();
                                var creditincome = $(this).find('.creditorincome01').val();
                                var alldata = {
                                    'myCreditorname': creditname,
                                    'myCreditoraddress': creditaddress,
                                    'myCreditorincome': creditincome
                                }
                                data.push(alldata);
                            });
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        }
                        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                            var empComplete = false, sourceComplete = false, spouseComplete = false, dividentComplete = false, reimbursedComplete = false, honorariaComplete = false, giftComplete = false, orgComplete = false, creditorComplete = false;
                            function checkComplete() {
                                if (empComplete && sourceComplete && spouseComplete && dividentComplete && reimbursedComplete && honorariaComplete && giftComplete && orgComplete && creditorComplete) {
                                    $("#result").text("All complete");
                                }
                            }
                            $("#result").text("");
                            var data = JSON.stringify(getAllEmpData());
                            console.log(data);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'closures.aspx/SaveEmpData',
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                                success: function () {
                                    empComplete = true;
                                    checkComplete();
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                            var data = JSON.stringify(getAllSourcepData());
                            console.log(data);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'closures.aspx/SaveSourceData',
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                                success: function () {
                                    sourceComplete = true;
                                    checkComplete();
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                            var data = JSON.stringify(getAllSpouseData());
                            console.log(data);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'closures.aspx/SaveSpousData',
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                                success: function () {
                                    spouseComplete = true;
                                    checkComplete();
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                            var data = JSON.stringify(getAllDividentData());
                            console.log(data);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'closures.aspx/SaveDividentData',
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                                success: function () {
                                    dividentComplete = true;
                                    checkComplete();
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                            var data = JSON.stringify(getAllReimbursedData());
                            console.log(data);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'closures.aspx/SaveReimbursedData',
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                                success: function () {
                                    reimbursedComplete = true;
                                    checkComplete();
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                            var data = JSON.stringify(getAllHonorariaData());
                            console.log(data);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'closures.aspx/SaveHonorariaData',
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                                success: function () {
                                    honorariaComplete = true;
                                    checkComplete();
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                            var data = JSON.stringify(getAllGiftData());
                            console.log(data);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'closures.aspx/SaveGiftData',
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                                success: function () {
                                    giftComplete = true;
                                    checkComplete();
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                            var data = JSON.stringify(getAllOrgData());
                            console.log(data);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'closures.aspx/SaveOrgData',
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                                success: function () {
                                    orgComplete = true;
                                    checkComplete();
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                            var data = JSON.stringify(getAllCreditorData());
                            console.log(data);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'closures.aspx/SaveCreditorData',
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                                success: function () {
                                    creditorComplete = true;
                                    checkComplete();
                                }
                             });
                         });
```

//Webmethods on codebehind:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function SaveEmpData(empdata As String) As String
        Dim serializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Employee))(empdata)
        Using con = New SqlConnection(Constr)
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If
            '  Dim cmdGetKey As New SqlCommand("Select Max(employeeID) From Employees", con)
            '  Dim ID As Integer = cmdGetKey.ExecuteScalar()

            For Each data As Employee In serializedData
                Using cmd1 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employees(EmployeeName,empTitle,email) Values (@ename, @title,@email)")
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ename", data.emplName)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", data.emplTitle)
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", data.empMail)
                    cmd1.Connection = con
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Dim cmdGetKey As New SqlCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", con)
                    Dim ID As Integer = cmdGetKey.ExecuteScalar()
                    HttpContext.Current.Session("empID") = ID
                End Using
            Next
            con.Close()
        End Using
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function SaveSourceData(empdata As String) As String
        '  Dim ID As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session("empID")
        Dim serializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of SourcDetails))(empdata)
        Using con = New SqlConnection(Constr)
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If
            '  Dim cmdGetKey As New SqlCommand("Select Max(employeeID) From Employees", con)
            '  Dim ID As Integer = cmdGetKey.ExecuteScalar()

            For Each data As SourcDetails In serializedData
                Using cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SourceDetails(sourcename, sourceaddress, sourceincome,employeeID) VALUES(@sname, @saddress,@sincome, @ID)")
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", data.mySource)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saddress", data.mySAddress)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sincome", data.mySIncome)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", HttpContext.Current.Session("empID"))
                    '  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", DateTime.Now)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            Next
            con.Close()
        End Using
        Return Nothing
    End Function
    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function SaveSpousData(empdata As String) As String
        '  Dim ID As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session("empID")
        Dim serializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of SpousDetails))(empdata)
        Using con = New SqlConnection(Constr)
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If
            '  Dim cmdGetKey As New SqlCommand("Select Max(employeeID) From Employees", con)
            '  Dim ID As Integer = cmdGetKey.ExecuteScalar()

            For Each data As SpousDetails In serializedData
                Using cmd2 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SpouseDetails(spousename, spouseaddress, spouseincome,employeeID) VALUES(@spname, @spaddress,@spincome, @ID)")
                    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spname", data.mySpouse)
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spaddress", data.mySPAddress)
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@spincome", data.mySPIncome)
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", HttpContext.Current.Session("empID"))
                    '  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", DateTime.Now)
                    cmd2.Connection = con
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            Next
            con.Close()
        End Using
        Return Nothing
    End Function
    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function SaveDividentData(empdata As String) As String
        '  Dim ID As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session("empID")
        Dim serializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of DividentDetails))(empdata)
        Using con = New SqlConnection(Constr)
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If
            '  Dim cmdGetKey As New SqlCommand("Select Max(employeeID) From Employees", con)
            '  Dim ID As Integer = cmdGetKey.ExecuteScalar()

            For Each data As DividentDetails In serializedData
                Using cmd3 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DividentDetails(dividentName, dividentAddress, dividentAmount,employeeID) VALUES(@divname, @divaddress,@divincome, @ID)")
                    cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@divname", data.myDivName)
                    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@divaddress", data.myDivAddress)
                    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@divincome", data.myDivIncome)
                    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", HttpContext.Current.Session("empID"))
                    '  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", DateTime.Now)
                    cmd3.Connection = con
                    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            Next
            con.Close()
        End Using
        Return Nothing
    End Function
    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function SaveReimbursedData(empdata As String) As String
        '  Dim ID As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session("empID")
        Dim serializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of ReimbursedDetails))(empdata)
        Using con = New SqlConnection(Constr)
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If
            '  Dim cmdGetKey As New SqlCommand("Select Max(employeeID) From Employees", con)
            '  Dim ID As Integer = cmdGetKey.ExecuteScalar()

            For Each data As ReimbursedDetails In serializedData
                Using cmd4 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ReimbursementDetails(reimbursementName, reimbursementAddress, reimbursementAmount,employeeID) VALUES(@reimbursename, @reimburseaddress,@reimburseincome, @ID)")
                    cmd4.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reimbursename", data.myReimbursName)
                    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reimburseaddress", data.myReimbursAddress)
                    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reimburseincome", data.myReimbursIncome)
                    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", HttpContext.Current.Session("empID"))
                    '  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", DateTime.Now)
                    cmd4.Connection = con
                    cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            Next
            con.Close()
        End Using
        Return Nothing
    End Function

Public Class Employee
    Public Property emplName() As String
        Get
            Return m_empName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_empName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_empName As String
    Public Property emplTitle() As String
        Get
            Return m_empTitle
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_empTitle = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_empTitle As String
    Public Property empMail() As String
        Get
            Return m_empMail
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_empMail = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_empMail As String
End Class
Public Class SourcDetails
    Public Property mySource() As String
        Get
            Return m_mySource
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_mySource = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_mySource As String
    Public Property mySAddress() As String
        Get
            Return m_mySAddress
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_mySAddress = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_mySAddress As String
    Public Property mySIncome() As String
        Get
            Return m_mySIncome
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_mySIncome = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_mySIncome As String

End Class
Public Class SpousDetails
    Public Property mySpouse() As String
        Get
            Return m_mySpouse
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_mySpouse = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_mySpouse As String
    Public Property mySPAddress() As String
        Get
            Return m_mySPAddress
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_mySPAddress = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_mySPAddress As String
    Public Property mySPIncome() As String
        Get
            Return m_mySPIncome
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_mySPIncome = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_mySPIncome As String

End Class
Public Class DividentDetails
    Public Property myDivName() As String
        Get
            Return m_myDivName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_myDivName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_myDivName As String
    Public Property myDivAddress() As String
        Get
            Return m_myDivAddress
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_myDivAddress = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_myDivAddress As String
    Public Property myDivIncome() As String
        Get
            Return m_myDivIncome
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_myDivIncome = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_myDivIncome As String

End Class
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should stop the submit function and then call the ajax method. Something like: 

 $('#your_form_id').submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be that the button-click automatically submits the `<form>` to the current URL, which causes a reload before the Ajax calls are executed. You can disable this default behaviour of the button with the code below:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault });
```

Also, you have a lot of duplicate code in the snippet you posted. Optimizing this will significantly improve readability, making debugging way easier. For example, the `.click()` below does the exact same as your code in way less lines of code.

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var posts = [{
        data: getAllEmpData,
        method: 'SaveEmpData'
    }, {
        data: getAllSourcepData,
        method: 'SaveSourceData'
    }, {
        data: getAllSpouseData,
        method: 'SaveSpousData'
    } /* ... */ ];

    var $result = $('#result');
    $result.text('');

    var calls = posts.map(function (p) {
        var data = p.data();
        console.log(data);

        return $.ajax({
            url: 'closures.aspx/' + p.method,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({'empdata': JSON.stringify(data)}),
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

    $.when.apply($, calls).then(function() {
        $result.text('All complete');
    });
});
```

Comment: Given the code I posted, where do I put that line?


I thought about e.preventDefault all day but did nothing with it!

Comment: @Kenny Putting the ` e.preventDefault` inside your existing `.click()` would probably be the nicest, but separately will work just fine too

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't solve it.

I replaced the existing btnSubmit click below 
`     $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {...`

with this:

`$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault }); {...` but sadly,no help.

Comment: @Kenny The page still reloads? Try putting the line `$('button').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault() })` above all of your other code. If the refreshing problem still exists then, it is caused by something else

Comment: The issue now is that when I click submit, I get seven of the eight error handlers for each ajax call. The exception is that data gets posted only to the Emp table.

Then I click submit again, this time, everything works fine. So, why is it posting only to the Emp table the first time and the rest of the tables the second time?

I am posting the webmethods above. Can someone please see if the issue is from there?

Comment: @Kenny That seems like a completely different issue to me than the reloading problem. I cannot help you with that, but I've added some info about clean code in my answer, which can help you find the problem. Your best bet is to create a new question for this new webmethods problem. And please accept my answer if it helped you fix your initial reloading problem.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. 

Your edited version looks elegant and might even fix my issue once I run it, who knows!

I just have one more question, my code has functions like `function getAllEmpData() {...` and the calls to those functions like `var data = JSON.stringify(getAllEmpData());...`

Does your version take care of both?

Comment: @Kenny You are already using `JSON.stringify` inside the `$.ajax()` call, so `JSON.stringify(getAllEmpData())` might not be necessary. Although if it does seem to be necessary, you can replace that line with `data: JSON.stringify({'empdata': JSON.stringify(p.data)})`. I've edited my answer to reflect these changes. Please let me know if it worked :)

Comment: but you still missed my question and that is, this part:

`    var posts = [{
        data: getAllEmpData,
        method: 'SaveEmpData'
    },`   and others that follow it, does it replace the functions like `function getAllEmpDate(), function getAllSourceData(), `  etc?

Comment: I tried your version of code and I am getting the following error:

{"Message": Type \u0027System.String \u0027 is not supported for deserialization of an array.",...

Comment: After I tried your latest changes, I am getting "error: function expected on the following line:

`var calls = posts.map(function (p) {`

Comment: @Kenny Sorry I misunderstood what you were asking. The `post.data` refers to the existing functions, so it does not replace it. The deserialization error might have to do with the double JSON.stringify call. You should test it both with and without that call

Comment: @Kenny I've also removed the parentheses from posts.data, you might have missed that

Comment: Sorry about too many messages. When I tried your code without the double JSON.stringify call, I get `{"Message": Type \u0027System.String \u0027 is not supported for deserialization of an array.",... `

When I tried it with the double JSON.stringify call, I get the following error:

`error: function expected on the following line:
`var calls = posts.map(function (p) {...`

Comment: @Kenny I think it should work with the double `JSON.stringify`. The error might come from `var data = p.data()`. You could try replacing that with `var data = p.data`. If that does not work I'm afraid I have to give up

Comment: I finally nailed down the problem.

On the asp side where the webmethods are used, I was trying to insert date into the employee table, grab the last inserted ID and then insert that along with some other records into the rest of the tables.

That obviously is causing problems.

Based on this and the preventDefault() you recommended, the original issue has been resolved and I thank you very much for your help in getting it resolved.

Comment: @Kenny I'm glad you figured it out :)